# How do I look up command-line documentation for Django?

Tags: command-line, python, documentation

I'm used to with Ubuntu, but it is a little bit different for Django. With Ubuntu, it is easy to find documentation about a command (i.e., `man ourcommand`), but what about Django. I mean when I go on the terminal when could install django with the simple command `pip install django`. After that, a guy has used the `pip3 freeze` command, and I was wondering if it is possible to do the same thing as with Ubuntu.

Is there  a command like `man` command but with django to find more information about a command (e.g. 'man' freeze)?

Comment: Generally speaking about packages in Ubuntu/Debian, documentation is available in `/usr/share/doc/<package>`. This is also [valid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/python-django/filelist) for the `python-django` package, but it will probably just point you to the online documentation of Django, I guess. For such library/framework packages as Django you might expect only Debian/Ubuntu specific documentation such as about migrations/upgrades which are specifically for the packaged version.

Comment: Apart from my comment above, documentation about the use of a software library/framework is different from help on a command line utility. For Django here I'd suggest to just use the online documentation and get yourself aware about the specifics on Ubuntu/Debian with the package installed with APT (opposed to using the upstream version with pip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case `man pip3` *(and then searching for `freeze` typing `/freeze`)* or `man pip3 | grep freeze` should do the trick, because *freeze* is an option of the `pip3` command.

Also many commands used developing with *Python* are related to python tools like `pip3` or `virtualenv`, so if you install them with `apt` you can search in the manual for their options.

As a bonus, you can build a *VM* or *Docker container* *(cleaner than installing on your system)* with Ubuntu and Django installed from `apt` (`sudo apt install python3-django`), and then search for man pages of Django-related terminal commands.

Hope it helps.